# Use of MFC in a COM server - what are my options?

Tags: com, printing, mfc, gdi

Visual C++. I have to implement some drawing and printing functionality that will be incorporated into (other developers') COM dll. Firstly I thought of doing everything using pure GDI and nothing more, but it seems that printing and print previewing is hell of a job to be done in GDI compared to the MFC implementation. So I decided to focus on MFC. Quick side question here: Is my choice right? I mean, are any easy ways of implementing printing (and print-preview) without MFC?

Now that I need MFC (assuming if you also agree with this), I have two questions about how to do it:

1) I believe the COM dll is the ATL project (it's not my code, some other developers independently develop it). Can I enable MFC support in that dll? What are the risks/limitations/drawbacks of having MFC runtime in the COM server? And if you advice doing this, how can I do it?

2) As much as I want to affect the third-party COM server's code as little as possible, I thought it might be the better approach to implement my code as a separate MFC-based DLL, and load and use that DLL from COM server. Do you advice doing this? What are the risks/limitations/drawbacks in this situation?

Shortly, I want to use MFC's drawing and especially printing capabilities in my code, which itself should be integrated in another developers' COM dll (which itself is utilized in a large corporate application). I'm no expert in COM technology so I'm a little bit confused. What are my best options?

Answer (score 0):

You can use MFC in your own dll internally, and expose functionality to your users with non MFC intruded function: for example if you need to pass a point from/to ypur caller, use the GDI standard POINT structure, then convert it to a CPoint to use internally. In this case you don't need to enamble use of MFC in the ATL project ( that is possible anyway ) but of course you need to distribute or link with the MFC dll. If you want mantain the caller com dll as clean as possible, you can definitely create your own ATL+MFC dll and expose your functions via com interfaces too, but keep in mynd to avoid put MFC related objects in the interface.

Answer (score 0):

Printing and print preview is a hell of a job unless you're using MFC [Document/View Architecture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4x1xy43a%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). Will your COM expose such advanced UI?

If your COM must be independent of .NET then MFC is the way to go, otherwise I would use .NET. If you choose MFC, make sure you link to it statically. Otherwise you will most likely end up with runtime errors on machines where the necessary MFC version is missing.

Except for this, I wouldn't worry about compatibility since the idea of COM is to let the underlying magic do the marshaling of integers, strings and other objects.